# Send XML Request on Huawei Router (E5186s-22a) to send SMS returns odd errors

Tags: c#, xml, huawei-mobile-services

I'm trying to send a XML request on C# to send a SMS with a Huawei E5186s-22a (some other routers used the same API).

I tried the following:

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.8.1/api/sms/sms-send");

httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

string requestXML = "<?xml version=1.0 encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><request><Index>-1</Index><Phones><Phone>+33xxxxxxxxx</Phone></Phones><Sca></Sca><Content>HELLO</Content><Length>29</Length><Reserved>1</Reserved><Date>2021-06-10 19:51:10</Date></request>";

byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestXML);

httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding=utf-8";

httpWebRequest.Accept = "text/xml";

httpWebRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

httpWebRequest.Headers["Cookie"] = "SessionID=omOV8okfQBdM13ApR0Q0XrXRbBsLSrBeNg4FGRhTG3BndqE9/U+fzmskGJYUEtZ6LDbW+bNe8Xf077r8mMGKd/blt/4CyzqzfqPgu3npi5FBJ3qRMQ7m3my1oTQ6XyBT";

httpWebRequest.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"] = "vL06UvKD1E2icwYPOWCxNUgbS90E6Yi+";

Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();

requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

requestStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse;

httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

if (httpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
    Stream responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
    string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(responseStr);
}
```

To those who may be more familiar with a CURL request, it looks like this:

```
curl -X POST "http://192.168.8.1/api/sms/sms-send" \
-H "Cookie: $COOKIE" -H "__RequestVerificationToken: $TOKEN" \
-H "Content-Type: text/xml" \
-H "Accept: text/xml" \
-d "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Request><Index>-1</Index><Phones><Phone>+33xxxxxxxxx</Phone></Phones><Sca></Sca><Content>Enfin</Content><Lenght>29</Lenght><Reserved>1</Reserved><Date>2021-06-10 19:12:55</Date></Request>"
```

However, I don't know if this request is invalid or not, but the router returns almost the same error as my C# code which may be 125002 (more frequent), 125003 and 100003.

The most frustrating thing is Huawei does not detail what are the meaning of these, so I'm assuming there's an error in these XML requests.

I have a huge doubt on this line :

`httpWebRequest.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"] = "[TOKEN HERE]";`

Is it the equivalent of this curl segment:

`-H "__RequestVerificationToken: [TOKEN HERE]"`

I hope someone could help me.

Comment: Do you have *any* documentation for it? I note as side points: the C# code is not disposing the streams or the response with `using` blocks, and you are encoding the XML in ASCII instead of UTF8, and you should probably construct XML with `XmlDocument` anyway.

Comment: The vendor has a support site. https://support.huawei.com/carrierindex/en/anony/index.html

Comment: @Charlieface Right, I'll try with XmlDocument. The closest documentation is this [one](https://support.huaweicloud.com/intl/en-us/api-msgsms/sms_05_0001.html) but error codes don't match, they don't specify if it's applicable to my router and finally other searches demonstrated the url is http://192.168.8.1/api/sms/send-sms